# install / repair help system

Tags: help-system, installing

I built vim from source on Arch Linux and the help system is not present. I do not see any help-related options when I do vim --version.

I assume it is either broken somehow or not installed. How can I fix it?

(Please don't tell me to reinstall it. Building it is a huge pain in the ass, and I do not want to repeat that process.)

Comment: How did you install? By calling `make install` or any other way? Which install location?

Comment: @Ralf by make install, /usr/bin/vim

Comment: In vim enter `:set helpfile?`. Does the displayed file exist. Guess it is `/usr/share/vim/vim81/doc/help.txt` in your case.

Comment: @Ralf It points to /usr/share/vim/doc/help.txt. There is no "doc" subdirectory in /usr/share/vim.

Comment: I assume you build Vim 8.1: Does `/usr/share/vim/vim81/doc` exist?

Comment: @Ralf It is 8.1. The only subdirectory in /usr/share/vim is "vimfiles". There is no vim81 directory.

Comment: Search your machine for a Vim help file. E.g. for `if_pyth.txt`.

Comment: @Ralf that file is present only in the source code directory (vim-git/src/vim/runtime/doc/if_python.txt)

Comment: IIRC tiny builds dont include the help; can you clarify any configure params/make variables you may have changed/set?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Its the "Huge" build.